# unable to read data from firebase using html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I can see data in a Firebase realtime database from the console but if I try to read this data via HTML/JavaScript it's not giving me anything. I have tried two different ways; neither worked.

Format of the data:

```
https://pump-a559c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/
Sensor
  pump1
    Cycle:217
    Duration:4.49222
    GalsPumped:26953.33203
    PumpID:1
    StartTime:"06:09:2022 17:55:39"
  pump2
    Cycle:7
    Duration:0.17806
    GalsPumped:1068.33325
    PumpID:2
    StartTime:"06:09:2022 17:30:03"
```

First way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {text-align: center;}
        #findDetails {float: left; width: 50%; background-color: floralwhite; color: darkslategray;}
        input {width: 120px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="findDetails">
        <h1>PUMP1</h1>

        <h3 id="Start-time" type="text"></h3>
        <h3 id="Cycle" type="text"></h3>
        <h3 id="Duration-hrs" type="text"></h3>
        <h3 id="Pumped-gals" type="text"></h3> <br><br>
    </div>

<script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app.js";
    import {getDatabase, ref, get, set, child, update, remove} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-database.js"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAKQ4cRyBMBbjhsYpg5w96wVj_-qE4zUGw",
  authDomain: "pump-a559c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://pump-a559c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "pump-a559c",
  storageBucket: "pump-a559c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "838180391277",
  appId: "1:838180391277:web:df22c7d634310ae135b264"
};

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Initialize the database
  const db = getDatabase(app);

  const dbref = ref(db);

    get(child(dbref, "Sensor"))
    .then((snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
            Start-time.innerHTML = "Start-time: " + child.val().StartTime;
            Cycle.innerHTML = "Cycle: " + child.val().Cycle;
            Duration-hrs.innerHTML = "Duration-hrs: " + child.val().Duration;
            Pumped-gals.innerHTML = "Pumped-gals: " + child.val().GalsPumped;
     //       console.log(child.val().StartTime);
        } else {
            alert("No data found");
        }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        alert(error);
       });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {text-align: center;}
        #findDetails {float: left; width: 50%; background-color: floralwhite; color: darkslategray;}
        input {width: 120px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
<ul id="list">

</ul>

<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.4/firebase-database.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-qE4zUGw",
      authDomain: "pump-a559c.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://pump-a559c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "pump-a559c",
      storageBucket: "pump-a559c.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "838180391277",
      appId: "1:838180391277:web:df22c7d634310ae135b264",
      measurementId: "G-K66Z05LFCD"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        
        var pumpId=0;
        function addItemsToList(starttime,cycle,duration,pumped){
            var ul=document.getElementById('list');
            var header= document.createElement('h2');
            
            var _starttime= document.createElement('li');
            var _cycle= document.createElement('li');
            var _duration= document.createElement('li');
            var _pumped= document.createElement('li');

            _starttime.innerHTML='Start-time: '+starttime;
            _cycle.innerHTML='Cycle: '+cycle;
            _duration.innerHTML='Duration-hrs: '+duration;
            _pumped.innerHTML='Pumped-gals: '+pumped;

            ul.appendChild(header);
            ul.appendChild(_starttime);
            ul.appendChild(_duration);
            ul.appendChild(_pumped);
        }

        function FetchAllData(){
            firebase.database().ref('Sensor').once('value',function(snapshot){
                snapshot.forEach(
                    function(ChildSnapshot){
                        let start = ChildSnapshot.val().StartTime;
                        let cycle = ChildSnapshot.val().Cycle;
                        let duration = ChildSnapshot.val().Duration;
                        let pumped = ChildSnapshot.val().GalsPumped;
                        addItemsToList(start,cycle,duration,pumped);
                    }
                );
            });
        }
        window.onload(FetchAllData());

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code resolved the issue and now I get my sensor data:

```
get(child(dbref, "Sensor"))
.then((snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
        id_PumpID.innerHTML = "Pump ID: " + child.val().PumpID
        id_StartTime.innerHTML = "StartTime: " + child.val().StartTime;
        id_Cycle.innerHTML = "Cycle: " + child.val().Cycle;
        id_Duration.innerHTML = "Duration: " +  child.val().Duration;
        id_GalsPumped.innerHTML ="GalsPumped: " + child.val().GalsPumped;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're loading the entire `Sensor` node, which means that you get a `snapshot` with data for all sensors. To get the data for each specific sensor, you'll need to loop over the child nodes in that snapshot.

So:

```
get(child(dbref, "Sensor")
.then((snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
        Start-time.innerHTML = "Start-time: " + child.val().StartTime;
        Cycle.innerHTML = "Cycle: " + child.val().Cycle;
        Duration-hrs.innerHTML = "Duration-hrs: " + child.val().Duration;
        Pumped-gals.innerHTML = "Pumped-gals: " + child.val().GalsPumped;
    });
})
.catch((error)=>{
    alert(error);
});
```

---

**Update**: the `Start-time` and other variables in your code are not defined, and in multiple cases not valid variables names. If you want to access an element from the DOM, you need to get it by calling `document.getElementById("Start-time")` and then call `innerHMTL` on its result.

So for example:

```
get(child(dbref, "Sensor")
.then((snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
        document.getElementById("Start-time").innerHTML = "Start-time: " + child.val().StartTime;
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: @Sami Have you tried to `console.log(child.val().StartTime);` ? have you tried using `document.getElementById('Start-time).innerHTML = "Start-time: " + child.val().StartTime;` ?

Comment: Parentheses & curly braces don't match. Should they be like the accepted self-answer? Are you missing a parenthesis on the 1st line for the get in both blocks & a curly brace in the 1st for the foreach--per your 2nd code block? (Presumably debugging your answer is why the self-answer rather than accepting yours.)